# Set raw_input answer as pre-defined variable

Tags: python, raw-input

Newbie here.

I wanted to have Python to look through the variables (in this case, john, clark, and bruce) and spit out the strings in those arrays, but I'm having no luck figuring out how. Here's the example I was working on:

```
names = ("john", "clark", "bruce")

john = ("doe", "13-apr-1985")
clark = ("kent", "11-jan—1987")
bruce = ("wayne", "05-sep-1988")

user = raw_input("What is your name?")
if user in names:
  print "Your last name is: " + ????[0]
  print "Your date of birth is: " + ????[1]
else:
  print "I don’t know you."
```

The question marks is where I am stuck. I don't know how to link the two together. I hope my question isn't too confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to map the first names to the tuples you have.

```
names = { "john": (“doe”, “13-apr-1985”),
          "clark": (“kent”, “11-jan—1987”),
          "bruce": (“wayne”, “05-sep-1988”)}

user = raw_input(“What is your name?”)
if user in names.keys():
  print “Your last name is: “ + names[user][0]
  print “Your date of birth is: “ + names[user][1]
else:
  print “I don’t know you.”
```

To make this even more pythonic and easier to work with, make a nested dictionary:

```
names = { "john": {"last": “doe”, "birthdate": “13-apr-1985”},
          "clark": {"last": “kent”, "birthdate": “11-jan—1987”},
          "bruce": {"last": “wayne”, "birthdate": “05-sep-1988”}}

user = raw_input(“What is your name?”)
if user in names.keys():
  print “Your last name is: “ + names[user]["last"]
  print “Your date of birth is: “ + names[user]["birthdate"]
else:
  print “I don’t know you.”
```

As a side note, you probably want to trim any leading whitespace off the input while you're at it.

```
...
user = raw_input(“What is your name?”)
user = user.strip()
if user in names.keys():
  ...
```

Comment: I really like the second example, thank you for that. Learned something new!

Comment: @Re-l - Yeah, dictionaries are awesome. Good luck with Python!

Comment: Sorry, one more question: where would I use "user = user.strip()"? Would it go before "if user in names.keys()"?

Comment: Right after you accept the raw_input, so yes, before you use it to check. This makes sure that if a newline is in their response like "john\n", it just turns into "john".

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary:

```
names = {
    "john": {
        "last_name": "doe",
        "date_of_birth": "13-apr-1985"
    },
}

user = raw_input("What is your name?")
if user in names:
    print "Your last name is: " + names[user]["last_name"]
    print "Your date of birth is: " + names[user]["date_of_birth"]
else:
    print "I don’t know you."
```

Note that this approach wouldn't work when multiple people have the same first name. In that case you need to adapt the data structure to handle that accordingly (and you need to decide whose results you're going to display when someone fills in `"john"`).

Comment: a possible implementation to properly handle duplicate first names would be to use `records = [name for name in names if record == user]` which will use list comprehension to create a list of the dicts matching the user input, then an `if len(records) > 1: lastname = raw_input("Multiple records found under {}, what is your last name?\n>>>".format(name))` then run the same list-comp for last name (`for firstname in records: record = [name for name in names if names[firstname]["last_name"] == lastname`)

Comment: Thank you both for your explanations.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `dict` here, like this

```
d = {"john" : ("doe", "13-apr-1985"),
     "clark" : ("kent", "11-jan-1987"),
     "bruce" : ("wayne", "05-sep-1988")}

...
...
if user in d:
    print “Your last name is: “ + d[user][0]
    print “Your date of birth is: “ + d[user][0]
else:
    print “I don’t know you.”
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know about 'dict'. Gotta do some reading.